# Pass dictionary to FxCop GUI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fxcop

I would like to open FxCop.exe (not the command line version) from VS 2010 with custom dictionary (Stored in a given path, not necessarily in FxCop folder) as a parameter. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done via the command line.  However, (from a bit of Reflector spelunking) it looks like the UI application probably supports adding custom dictionaries via `CustomDictionary` nodes inside the `CustomDictionaries` node of an .fxcop project file.

Comment: You are correct. It cannot be done via the command line directly.

Comment: You can now (with at least with the FXCop version that ships with VS2013) for the command line add the argument  `/dictionary:..\SomeFolder\CustomDictionary.xml`. To add it to the command that Visual Studio runs add `<CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions> /dictionary:..\SomeFolder\CustomDictionary.xml </CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions>` to your (cs|vb)proj file

Comment: @Bigwave: FxCop.exe does not support the same command line options as FxCopCmd.exe.  The last version of FxCop.exe that was released shipped with FxCop 10.0.  No version of Visual Studio so far has included the FxCop.exe UI application.